# How to get list of users who have installed the app for Google workspace Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I just got an app published on Google Workspace marketplace, I am having issues in knowing who have installed the app, since the Callback URL is not being called in Installation.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*There is no way of directly retrieving this information.*

#### More Information:

As a developer of a Google Workspace Marketplace add-on you can get insights on how many users and how many domains have installed your add-on from the GCP console, but there is no direct way to get a list of the users that installed the add-on directly. I imagine this is for security reasons.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Rafa  for replying back , i will need the user to automatically register on my application side too, and send that user an onboarding email for next steps, i am not sure how to do it if the user comes from or registers from the Google Workspace markeplace , please advise